# Problems running Angular 2 quickstart from an Apache virtual root

Tags: .htaccess, angular, mod-rewrite

I am just trying to get the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to work correctly when running under an apache virtual root.  When I use the lite server with `npm start` and navigate to http://localhost:3000, the app works fine.  When I navigate to the app through apache at http://localhost/myvirt, I get a boatload of 404 errors.

I assume this is an issue with the deep linking routing that Angular requires, and I've seen suggestions to use mod_rewrite within .htaccess or the HashLocationStrategy within angular. I want to have urls without the hashes, so I'd prefer to use the mod_rewrite method and that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

My folder structure is the quickstart app's structure and looks like so:

```
C:\apache\myvirtualroot
  +- node_modules
  |   +- ....
  +- src
  |   +- app
  |   |   +- app.component.js
  |   |   +- app.module.js
  |   +- index.html
  |   +- main.js
  |   +- styles.css
  |   +- systemjs.config.extras.js
  |   +- systemjs.config.js
  |   +- systemjs-angular-loader.js
  +- .htaccess
```

Here's what I've done:

1. Created my virtual root (myvirt) in apache that points to C:\apache\myvirtualroot.
2. Made sure mod_rewrite was enabled and `AllowOverride any` was set.
3. Created a .htaccess file in my virtual root, and made sure it was being recognized by the server.
4. Pointed my browser to http://localhost/myvirt, and got the directory listing from apache.
5. Navigated to /src/ and it loaded my index.html file, which generated lots more 404 errors as it tried to start up angular.

Then I created my .htaccess to try to rewrite everything into the index.html file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myvirt/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . src/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The result of this was a slightly different set of 404s and syntax errors, since it seemed like the js resources angular was trying to load were instead resulting in my index.html file being returned by apache.

I am at minimum a little confused about the relationship between these things:

1. **the apache virtual root** -- should it point to the folder that *contains* "src" or to "src" itself?
2. **the html `<base>`** -- I assume it should be `/myvirt/` in my case.
3. **the RewriteBase directive in .htaccess** -- Should it reflect the same value as my html `<base>`?
4. **the RewriteRule directive** -- This is currently correctly pointing to the index.html, though the current combination of values is causing most angular files to be rewritten as index.html.

I can't seem to wrap my head around a correct combination of these values that should work together to convince angular 2 to work here.

So, how can I set up my virtual root and .htaccess to correctly launch this simple angular 2 app?

Answer (score 0):

I've been wading through the same and have the app serving off Apache this morning using the following:

1. In the .conf file for the site I have the Apache document root set to the root directory of the application. However since I created this app with the Angular CLI index.html lives in /dist after compilation. Therefore I've added a node with: `<directory app-url/dist>AllowOverride All</directory>` to the .conf file.
2. You are correct about the  tag in index.html.
3. I am not using RewriteBase in .htaccess. I do have `DocumentRoot ./dist/`
4. I have `RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]`

Finally, I have a symlink for index.html at my root URL forwarding to the actual index.html in the dist folder. Now that site is up, next step is testing whether HTML5 hash-less routing is working :-)